# Powerbuilder - to get a Unique filename

Tags: powerbuilder

I am looking for  the code how to get a unique file name in Powerbuilder 11 version. I am using the function. I am using  the following code , but not working

```
FUNCTION integer GetTempFileName (ref string tempdir, ref string prefix, integer seed, ref string tempfile ) LIBRARY "kernel32" alias for "GetTempFileNameW"

string ls_prefixe = "app"
integer li_seed = 0
string ls_filename
ls_filename = space(256)

li_rc = GetTempFileName(ls_tempdir, ls_prefixe, li_seed, ls_filename)
IF li_rc = 0 THEN
    MessageBox("Oups", "Error")
ELSE
    MessageBox("Unique filename", ls_filename)
END IF
```

Comment: just with adding the missing `int li_rc` and `string ls_tempdir` your code is working with my PB11. What is "not working"? Error message, syntax error?

Answer (score 1):

This works:

Global External Function:

```
FUNCTION integer GetTempFileName (ref string tempdir, ref string prefix, integer seed, ref string tempfile ) LIBRARY "kernel32" alias for "GetTempFileNameA;ANSI"
```

Code:

```
integer li_rc 
string ls_tempdir = "c:\temp\"
string ls_prefixe = "app"
integer li_seed = 0
string ls_filename

ls_filename = space(256)

li_rc = GetTempFileName(ls_tempdir, ls_prefixe, li_seed, ls_filename)
IF li_rc = 0 THEN
   MessageBox("Oups", "Error")
ELSE
   MessageBox("Unique filename", ls_filename )
END IF
```

Comment: Using the `__;ANSI;` functions aliases should be reserved for compatibility issues when calling old non-unicode dll functions or when reusing old pre-10 legacy code. PB is internally using `wide_char`string types since the 10.0 release and can use the `__W` windows API functions. Using the ansi variants add an overload to the calls by converting the string between `char` and `wchar_t` format before and after the calls.

Comment: Well, there is no problem, just change the Global External Function by the following: FUNCTION integer GetTempFileName (ref string tempdir, ref string prefix, integer seed, ref string tempfile) LIBRARY "kernel32" alias for "GetTempFileNameW"

Answer (score 0):

Why not use PowerBuilder to do this and not a Windows API?  You can easily generate random values using the Randomize method.  Since the output is an integer, you can generate multiple values and concatenate them together.

Example:

```
String(Randomize(0)) + String(Randomize(0))
```

Then use that as your filename.

Comment: Because it is bricolage to reinvent the wheel while the system can provide a facility to get a guaranteed unique file name? If the first file name is not unique for some reason, the API increase the seed number until getting a truly unique file name.

Comment: I tried to use Randomize(0) with my filename but it doesn't come random number. But when I use the given  script , it does generate unique number